# nopCommerce: Database does not exist or you don't have permission to connect to it

Tags: sql-server, azure, firewall, nopcommerce

While trying to **install nopCommerce** in Azure, I get the following error: Database does not exist or you don't have permissions to connect to it. :(

[image: Problem]

**The process** I've been through was quite straightforward:

1. [Get nopCommerce](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/nopCommerce.nopCommerce)
2. Give a name to the app
3. Create the Resource Group
4. Define the App Service plan / Location
5. Create a SQL server
6. Create a DB
7. Create a SQL Admin user
8. Allow connections from my IP to all the databases in the DB server in the SQL Server Firewall

The problem is quite explanatory but I can't seem to fix it.

[This link tells the process one needs to go through in order to troubleshoot](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/).

What shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed it** by selecting "Enter raw connection string".

In order to get that string, inside of the Azure Portal, went to Connection Strings and got it from there adjusting to the message prompt while selection the raw connection string option.

[image]